# Dictionary Values Printing Out Unusual/Weird Numbers

Tags: python

I was trying to solve a problem on codechef (https://www.codechef.com/problems/UCL) and I was so confused why the numbers that were being printed were completely incorrect and I literally have no idea how those numbers even came to be.

I have a file for the input here: input.txt

```
2
manutd 8 vs. 2 arsenal
lyon 1 vs. 2 manutd
fcbarca 0 vs. 0 lyon
fcbarca 5 vs. 1 arsenal
manutd 3 vs. 1 fcbarca
arsenal 6 vs. 0 lyon
arsenal 0 vs. 0 manutd
manutd 4 vs. 2 lyon
arsenal 2 vs. 2 fcbarca
lyon 0 vs. 3 fcbarca
lyon 1 vs. 0 arsenal
fcbarca 0 vs. 1 manutd
a 3 vs. 0 b
a 0 vs. 0 c
a 0 vs. 0 d
b 0 vs. 0 a
b 4 vs. 0 c
b 0 vs. 0 d
c 0 vs. 0 a
c 0 vs. 0 b
c 1 vs. 0 d
d 3 vs. 0 a
d 0 vs. 0 b
d 0 vs. 0 c
```

And here is my code which is printing out the weird numbers:

```
fh = open('competitiveProgrammingInput.txt', "r")
tc = int(fh.readline())

for i in range(tc):
    teamsList = {}
    highest = 0
    for i in range(12):
        homeScore = 0
        awayScore = 0
        li = fh.readline().split()
        home, homeG, awayG, away = li[0], int(li[1]), int(li[3]), li[4]

        if homeG > awayG:
            homeScore = 3
            awayScore = 0
        elif awayG > homeG:
            awayScore = 3
            homeScore = 0
        elif awayG == homeG:
            homeScore = 1
            awayScore = 1

        homeDifference = homeG - awayG
        awayDifference = awayG - homeG


        if home in teamsList:
            homeDifference = homeDifference + teamsList[home][1]
            homeScore += teamsList[home][0]
            del teamsList[home]
            newD = {home: [homeScore, homeDifference]}
            teamsList[home] = [homeScore, homeDifference]
        else:
            teamsList[home] = [homeScore, homeDifference]

        if away in teamsList:
            awayDifference = awayDifference + teamsList[away][1]
            awayScore = awayDifference + teamsList[away][0]
            del teamsList[away]
            newD = {away: [awayScore, awayDifference]}
            teamsList[away] = [awayScore, awayDifference]
        else:
            teamsList[away] = [awayScore, awayDifference]

    print(teamsList)
```

Specifically, it is the **homeScore** and **awayScore** values that are not working.

To give you some context, this problem is to get ranking for a soccer tournament, the format for the input goes like **Home team, Home Team Goals, 'vs', Away Team Goals, Away Team** Whoever made more goals gets +3 score. and that is the awayScore and homeScore variables.

The numbers being put out have no correlation with anything I can think of.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Maybe you're reading the wrong file? You said the filename is input.txt but the code says competitiveProgrammingInput.txt.

Comment: Can you share the current and expected output?

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points here:

- Why are you deleting keys from your dictionary and then adding them back? You don't have to do that because the values should update.
- Why are you setting up `newD`? You're not using that anywhere.

As for your actual problem, you're updating `awayScore` with `awayDifference` so perhaps the line should look like:

```
awayScore += teamsList[away][0]
```

I suspect that's not your only problem, though. You said in your question that the winning team get's a +3 score, but they also get a +1 if the match results in a draw. Furthermore, your score difference will be negative for the losing team. Are these values expected?

However, the architecture of your code is strange because you're using the values to modify other values and then overwriting the originals. To take the "away" branch of your code, perhaps you should try it like this:

```py
if away in teamsList:
    teamsList[away][1] += awayDifference
    teamsList[away][0] += awayScore
else:
    teamsList[away] = [awayScore, awayDifference]
```

and then you can do the same for the "home" branch.

However, this is not the best practice because it's easy to get confused between which index corresponds to a "score" versus a "difference". In fact, that's what tripped you up here. Instead, I would add a class:

```py
class TeamEntry:

    def __init__(self, score, difference):
        self.Score = score
        self.Difference = difference

    def Add(self, score, difference):
        self.Score += score
        self.Difference += difference
```

Then, you "away" branch would look like:

```py
if away in teamsList:
    teamsList[away].Add(awayScore, awayDifference)
else:
    teamsList[away] = TeamEntry(awayScore, awayDifference)
```

which is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

With code fixes to original code

**Code**

```
fh = open('competitiveProgrammingInput.txt', "r")
tc = int(fh.readline())

for i in range(tc):
    teamsList = {}
    highest = 0
    for i in range(12):
        homeScore = 0
        awayScore = 0
        li = fh.readline().split()
        home, homeG, awayG, away = li[0], int(li[1]), int(li[3]), li[4]

        if homeG > awayG:
            homeScore = 3
            awayScore = 0
        elif awayG > homeG:
            awayScore = 3
            homeScore = 0
        elif awayG == homeG:
            homeScore = 1
            awayScore = 1

        homeDifference = homeG - awayG
        awayDifference = awayG - homeG

        if home in teamsList:
            homeDifference += teamsList[home][1]
            homeScore += teamsList[home][0]
            teamsList[home] = [homeScore, homeDifference]
        else:
            teamsList[home] = [homeScore, homeDifference]

        if away in teamsList:
            awayDifference += teamsList[away][1]
            awayScore += teamsList[away][0]
            teamsList[away] = [awayScore, awayDifference]
        else:
            teamsList[away] = [awayScore, awayDifference]

    # Sort by points then by goal difference
    results = sorted(teamsList.items(), key=lambda kv: tuple(kv[1]), reverse=True) 
    # Print first two names of results (since sorted in descending order)
    print(*[name for name, value in results[:2]])
```

**Output**

```
manutd fcbarca
d b
```